# Fixing the scrollview with textview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Have a look at this.

[image]

In my app when I'm scrolling what behind the title appears how can I fix it please

Here is my XML.file

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Frame Relay"
        android:textColor="#F4661B"
        android:textColorHint="#6600FF"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic" />
        <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/pourframerelay"
        android:textColor="#FAEBD7"
        android:textColorHint="#FAEBD7" />

        </ScrollView>
```

thank you again
my xml file

Comment: show your layout xml problem lies their.

Comment: Why don't you include your code (layout XML file)

Comment: might b its starting from their only in xml, u have found while scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove from ScrollView line:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

and put instead this one:

```
android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
```

Answer (score 0):

check the how the scrollable view / listview is setup. if the title is overlapping the view and cutting your data then mostly the container has limits larger than visible region. Keep the title and view next each other not title over listview